# Insert into Table with the first column being a Sequence

Tags: plsql, sequence, subquery

I am trying to use an Insert, Sequence and Select * to work together.

```
INSERT INTO BRK_INDV
Select * from (Select brk_seq.NEXTVAL as INDV_SEQ, a.*
FROM (select to_date(to_char(REQUEST_DATETIME,'DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY') BUSINESS_DAY, to_char(REQUEST_DATETIME,'hh24') src_hour, 
CASE tran_type
WHEN 'V' THEN 'Visa'
WHEN 'M' THEN 'MasterCard'
ELSE tran_type
end text,
tran_type, count(*) as count 
from DLY_STATS
where 1=1
AND to_date(to_char(REQUEST_DATETIME,'DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY') = '09-FEB-2015'
group by to_date(to_char(REQUEST_DATETIME,'DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY'),to_char(REQUEST_DATETIME,'hh24'),tran_type order by src_hour)a);
```

This gives me the following error:

```
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here
```

I tried to remove the order by and still the same error.

However, if I only run

```
Select brk_seq.NEXTVAL as INDV_SEQ, a.*
FROM (select to_date(to_char(REQUEST_DATETIME,'DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY') BUSINESS_DAY, to_char(REQUEST_DATETIME,'hh24') src_hour, 
CASE tran_type
WHEN 'V' THEN 'Visa'
WHEN 'M' THEN 'MasterCard'
ELSE tran_type
end text,
tran_type, count(*) as count 
from DLY_STATS
where 1=1
AND to_date(to_char(REQUEST_DATETIME,'DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY') = '09-FEB-2015'
group by to_date(to_char(REQUEST_DATETIME,'DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY'),to_char(REQUEST_DATETIME,'hh24'),tran_type order by src_hour)a;
```

It shows me proper entries. Then, why is select * not working for that?
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you're trying to do. You want to insert rows into the BRK_INDV table in a particular order. The sequence number, which I assume will be the primary key of BRK_INDV, will be generated sequentially in the sorted order of the input rows.

You are working with a relational database. One of the first characteristics we all learn about a relational database is that the order of the rows in a table is insignificant. That's just a fancy word for *fugitaboutit*.

You cannot assume that a `select * from table` will return the rows in the same order they were written. It might. It might for quite a long time. Then something -- the number of rows, the grouping of some column values, the phase of the moon -- *something* will change and you will get them out in a seemingly totally random order.

If you want order, it must be imposed in the query, *not* the insert.

Here's the statement you should be executing:

```
INSERT INTO BRK_INDV
With
Grouped( Business_Day, Src_Hour, Text, Tran_Type, Count )As(
    Select  Trunc( Request_Datetime ) Business_Day,
            To_Char( Request_Datetime, 'hh24') Src_Hour,
        Case Tran_Type
            When 'V' Then 'Visa'
            When 'M' Then 'MasterCard'
            Else Tran_Type
        end Text,
        Tran_Type, count(*) as count 
    from DLY_STATS
    Where 1=1 --> Generated as dynamic SQL?
        And Request_Datetime >= Date '2015-02-09'
        And Request_Datetime < Date '2015-02-10'
    Group By Trunc( Request_Datetime ), To_Char( Request_Datetime, 'hh24'), Tran_Type
)
Select  brk_seq.Nextval Indv_Seq, G.*
from    Grouped G;
```

Notice there is no `order by`. If you want to see the generated rows in a particular order:

```
select * from Brk_Indv order by src_hour;
```

Since there could be hundreds or thousands of transactions in any particular hour, you probably order by something other than hour anyway.

In Oracle, the `trunc` function is the best way to get a date with the time portion stripped away. However, you don't want to use it in the `where` clause (or, aamof, any other function such as `to_date` or `to_char`)as that would make the clause non-sargable and result in a complete table scan.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't use a sequence in a subquery. For example, this gives the same `ORA-02287` error you are getting:

```
create table T (x number);

create sequence s;

insert into T (select * from (select s.nextval from dual));
```

What you can do, though, is create a function that returns nextval from the sequence, and use that in a subquery:

```
create function f return number as
begin
  return s.nextval;
end;
/

insert into T (select * from (select f() from dual));
```